# spring secuirty anonymous user and authenticated user with spring security

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi am new to spring security.

i had tried with anonymous user for access the application.
but now i want to implement both anonymous user and authenticated user access the application .can any one help me.

the following security.xml i had used for anonymous users.but now i want to implement anonymous user and authenticated users.(authenticated users sample registered users username and password to checking)

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/static/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="**/static/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/w/login*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/w/about*" security="none" />    
    <http pattern="/w/getInvolved*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/w/faq*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/w/feedback*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/w/contact*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/w/privacy*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/w/terms*" security="none" />
    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">

    <form-login login-page='/w/login' />

    <intercept-url pattern="/w/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/a/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <logout logout-url="/w/logout"  logout-success-url="/w/login" />
  </http>


  <authentication-manager>
     <authentication-provider user-service-ref="twwiUserSQLMapDAO">
        <password-encoder hash="sha"></password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
  </beans:beans>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more details to your question; as it stands, it risks being put on hold.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give access to authenticated and anonymous users you can use permitAll:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments.I had already used like these permitAll and isAuthenticated().but i want to redirect with the authorities.so for that only i has asked any sample code with full mvc structure .

Comment: Sorry, I dont't understand you. Can you please ask your question in other words?

Comment: okay.i had tried with different access as isAnonymous and isAuthenitcated and permitAll access roles.but i want some sample code for both authenticated user and anonymous user spring full mvc structure code.(sample project code).